# Where to code my unset tokken on my specific php proces structure?

Tags: php, forms

Hello i'm near at the finish of my form coding including validation and stuff , as wee all now we want to prevent users or spams from multi submitting our forms. So i want to include the hidden token method in my script but i dont figure out where to code my

```
unset( $_SESSION['form_token']);  or what i need in my process.php
```

Let start with my form.php :

```
<?php

        session_start();
        $form_token = uniqid();
        $_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;
?>
```

and my hidden tokken input :

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
```

yet the part i get in trouble i have 3 radios inside my form that determine the next page after submiting here my code the proces.php code :

```
<?php

require_once('formvalidator.php');
  if(isset($_POST['form_btn'])) {
     $validator = new simple_fv;

        // fields info container
        $fields = array();

        // fill the container with fields data
        $fields[] = array('index'=>'name', 'label'=>'Name', 'required'=>true, 'max_len'=>25);
        $fields[] = array('index'=>'surname', 'label'=>'surname', 'required'=>true, 'max_len'=>30);
         $indexes[] = array('index'=>'email', 'label'=>'E-mail', 'required'=>true, 'type'=>'email', 'max_len'=>200);
          $fields[] = array('index'=>'phone', 'label'=>'phone number',   'min_len'=>4);
          $fields[] = array('index'=>'country', 'label'=>'Country');

        // get errors
        $error = $validator->getErrors();

        // if errors is not FALSE - print the succesfull message

    if($error) {echo $error;} 
    else {if( isset($_POST['name']) )


    $emotion = $_POST['emotion']; 

    if($emotion == 'Basic Pack') { 
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['form_token'] = true; 
    header('Location: /new/basicc.php'); 
    } elseif($emotion == 'Deluxe Pack') { 
    header('Location: html6.php'); 
    } elseif($emotion == 'Premium Pack') { 
    header('Location: html7.php'); 
    }
```

This is just a shorten version but i dont figure out where to code  `unset( $_SESSION['form_token']);`

or

```
 elseif($_POST['form_token'] != $_SESSION['form_token'])
        {
                $message = 'Access denied';
        }
```

So the idea is that with this to prevent user after submitting the form to go back and have all fields filled it should so that they will be directed to an error or the form.php but with clean fieldset Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to unset the session variable since you're never instantiating it in this case unless there is a valid token:

`if $_POST['form_token'] {
     session_start(); 
     $_SESSION['form_token'] = true;
} else {
     echo 'Access Denied!';
}`

If your script redirects to one of the other form pages, just check for the `$_SESSION` before allowing them to continue.

Comment: can you please be more specific since i'm a beginer in php where to put what , thanks in advance